# fiber networking: making sure I understand

Tags: fiber, switch

Im costing out a network in a building that has multi-mode fiber already available. It's entirely unused and requires switching in multiple locations to make a working system.

I want to make sure that I fully understand what's involved in hooking it up. Is this list inclusive?

1. 1000base sx to rj45 converter - this gets me from fiber to cat-5(**)
2. SFP style switching - vendor notwithstanding
3. GBIC on either end of existing fiber to connect to adapter on one end and switch on the other

(**) PC of some sort at this point

If I provide an internet drop at one end, could I connect to each cat-5 location using a system like this? Assume that I have enough IP addresses to cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the fiber to trunk between switches, or as a solid connection beyond the 100m limit of ethernet. I've run multimode fiber for the two examples I provided earlier.

All you really need are central switches with GBIC ports, connect those to switches with GBIC trunk ports on the edge, and plenty of classic ethernet ports for client connectivity.

Comment: I'll have to provide switching at two locations: every three floors where 15 apartments are terminated and at the basement where 10 lines (30 floors) are terminated.

Comment: Exactly, in the basement you could use a pure fiber/GBIC switch and for the apartment terminations smaller switches with multiple ethernet ports, and a few GBIC ports for the trunk to the central switch.

Comment: ok - but essentially its: rj45 -> GBIC -> switch -> GBIC -> fiber -> GBIC -> switch -> 'outside world'?

Comment: The way I did it was: [client] RJ45 <--(ethernet)--> RJ45 [switch] GBIC <--(fiber)--> GBIC [central switch]

Comment: Close enough! TY

Comment: no problems, you're welcome.